# Resize view if subview (un-)hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS programming and have a portion of interface that looks like this:
[image]

What I want it to behave like, is when there are no rows in this table view, the label and a scrollview that contains tableview should be hidden, and parent UIView (gray one) should only wrap text field (preserving margins of course). If some rows are added to the table view (by entering text in text field), the label and table view should appear and this parent UIView should resize to wrap them too. When its height reaches makes it so big that it reaches bottom margin, it shouldn't expand anymore. How to achieve that?

EDIT: to make it more clear, I know how to add rows to table view, how to hide elements, what I don't know is how to resize this parent UIView.

EDIT 2: to make it even more clear for some people: when I hide subviews, their parent view (gray area) has the same size as before, which is similar behavior to what LinearLayout does on Android when its children are hidden. What I want it is to behave like LinearLayout when its children are GONE instead of HIDDEN.

Comment: Tell me more. How you store your data? What is the `datasource` for this `tableview` (array, array controller, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

use

label.hidden=YES;

scrollView.hidden=YES;

use this

Comment: I know what to do in order to hide those elements, but even when they are hidden, this parent UIView appears to remain big enough to accomodate them. I want it to resize only to fit visible subviews

Comment: create another frame for that condition. so when the cell count is zero change the view's frame. is that ohke?

Comment: Yeah, that might work, though I thought there might be some better mechanism for that.

Comment: donno if there is one. this one just striked in my mind. if there is any other method please comment it.

Answer (score 1):

my laconic reply:

```
tableview.superview
```

Oh. I'd doing same trick, but with `uiTextView` and its contextSize. I can search code if it help you, but `uiview` and `uitableview` don't have `contextSize` property.

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoLayout is the best way to achieve this, but since you have not mentioned using it you can try something like this,

place tableview relative to label,
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height,width,height);

when u call label.hidden = YES, make label's height '0'

once u reset frames for ui elements call setNeedsDisplay/setNeedsLayout to redraw views.